# How can I replace new lines with \n character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Data stored in the database is like this:

```
This is a line

This is another line

How about this line
```

When I output it to the view, I want to convert that to:

```
This is a line\n\nThis is another line\n\nHow about this line
```

with no new lines and the actual `\n` characters printed out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> s = "hi\nthere"
> puts s
hi
there
> puts s.gsub(/\n/, "\\n")
hi\nthere
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use `gsub` if you only want newlines specifically converted. However, if you want to generally inspect the contents of the string, do this:

```
str = "This is a line\n\nThis is another line\n\nHow about this line"
puts str.inspect[1..-2]
#=> This is a line\n\nThis is another line\n\nHow about this line
```

The `String#inspect` method escapes various 'control' characters in your string. It also wraps the string with `"`, which I've stripped off above. Note that this may produce undesirable results, e.g. the string `My name is "Phrogz"` will come out as `My name is \"Phrogz\"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
> s = "line 1\n\nline2"
 => "line 1\n\nline2"  

> puts s
line 1

line2

> puts s.gsub("\n", "\\n")
line 1\n\nline2
```

The key is to [escape the single backslash](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences).